# Opengl es2 Zooming and Panning Slowly

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm displaying openstreetmap data on android with opengl everything is ok so far but while working with relatively big data file (>10Mo) my zoom and pan functionalities don't work smooth it is just too slow.
Inside the renderer i have these lines of code

```
 
    echelle=OsmGLSurfaceView.mScaleFactor;
    Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix,0,  left/ (float)echelle, right/ (float)echelle,bottom/(float)echelle,top/ (float)echelle,1,25);
    Matrix.translateM(mProjectionMatrix,0,6*OsmGLSurfaceView.mPosX/(float)echelle,-6*OsmGLSurfaceView.mPosY/(float)echelle,0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    osmf.draw(mMVPMatrix);
```

i use a scalegesturedetector in the glsurfaceview to get the scalefactor and the x,y positions needed for panning
As i said everything works perfect with very small data file

Where am i getting this wrong?

Comment: Please do a profiling and post here what functionality is the top timeconsumer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer some while ago, maybe it might help somebody one day. there was nothing wrong with the zooming or panning functionalities the problem was rather with the number of draw() calls wich where really causing a very slow rendering. So the only rule while programming with OpenGL ES 2 is to have a minimum call for the draw() method which will reduce the exchange of data between CPU and GPU doing that will just faster your application. You really need to use OpenGL routines such as GL_LINE or GL_POINT to their best to obtain a fast rendering!